# How to remove upload button in Kartik File Input Widget

Tags: php, forms, yii2, widget

I am now creating a form for uploading photos using Kartik File Input Widget in yii2 framework.

Visit http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/fileinput

In that widget, "Upload" Button function is similar to "Submit" Button in form. So I would like to remove that "Upload" Button of Kartik File Input Widget. Where can I change code in order to remove that "Upload" button in code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in widget configuration:

```
'pluginOptions' => [
    'showUpload' => false
],
```

Comment: Thank you for help

Comment: How to remove delete button as well? 'showDelete' => false, its not working

Comment: There is `showRemove` - have you spent at least 30 seconds reading the docs?